# Different errors when trying to a bibliography using APA style in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, citing, templates, apa-style, overleaf

I am really new to LateX and tried to do APA citation (Author, Year) in many ways using Overleaf 
for my thesis, but without success. 
I am using the following template:

> https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tut-slash-ttu-thesis-template/fczbvgdpbjtf

and the document that contains all the references is called library.bib

```
@article{Pelczar2016,
    title = {{A pathogenic role for T cell–derived IL-22BP in inflammatory bowel disease}},
    year = {2016},
    journal = {Science},
    author = {Pelczar, Penelope and Witkowski, Mario and Perez, Laura Garcia and Kempski, Jan and Hammel, Anna G and Brockmann, Leonie and Kleinschmidt, Dörte and Wende, Sandra and Haueis, Cathleen and Bedke, Tanja and Witkowski, Marco and Krasemann, Susanne and Steurer, Stefan and Booth, Carmen J and Busch, Philipp and K{\"{o}}nig, Alexandra and Rauch, Ursula and Benten, Daniel and Izbicki, Jakob R and R{\"{o}}sch, Thomas and Lohse, Ansgar W and Strowig, Till and Gagliani, Nicola and Flavell, Richard A and Huber, Samuel},
    number = {6310},
    month = {10},
    pages = {358 LP  - 362},
    volume = {354},
    url = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/354/6310/358.abstract},
    doi = {10.1126/science.aah5903}
```

This is a part of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage[apacite]

\begin{document}
...
\cite{Sato2013}
\cite{Pelzcar2016}
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

However, I only get the error:

```
'\bibliographystyle' invalid. \bibliographystyle'
'can be used only in preamble. \bibliography'
```

I also tried different citation styles using the following commands:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{library.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

but then I got the error: `Option clash for package biblatex` and
`Citation undefined on line xx`

I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\printbibliography` is a `biblatex` command, and  other biblatex commands are missing, whereas `\bibliographystyle{...}` is *not* used by biblatex. You did not show all the code related to bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

Your test document doesn't compile when using the `apacite` citation management package and the associated `apacite` bibliography style because it contains two errors -- one syntax error, one consequential typo.

- You must use curly braces, not square brackets, to denote the argument of LaTeX directives. Thus, write `\usepackage{apacite}`, *not* `\usepackage[apacite]`.
- The argument of `\cite` must correspond to an entry in the bib file. Since the entry's key is `Pelczar2016`, the citation command has got to be `\cite{Pelczar2016}`, *not* `\cite{Pelzcar2016}`.

After making the required adjustments, the test document compiles just fine.

[image]

---

*Addendum*: If you wanted to use the `biblatex` package rather than the `apacite6` package while sticking to the formatting guidelines of the 6th edition of the APA manual for the appearance of the bibliography and the citation call-outs, you should change the instructions

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

to

```
\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
```

in the preamble and change `\bibliography{library}` to `\printbibliography` in the body of the document. And, be sure to use `biber` rather than `bibtex` as the background program.

Incidentally, if you wanted to follow the *latest version* -- which is no longer version 6, but version 7 -- of the APA formatting guidelines, you should change `[style=apa6]` to `[style=apa]`. One of the immediately apparent changes brought about by APA7 is that the list of authors is truncated only if an entry has more than 20 authors; under APA6, the truncation cut-off was set at 8.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} % using 'article' just for this MWE
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{library.bib}
@article{Pelczar2016,
    title = {{A pathogenic role for T cell–derived IL-22BP in inflammatory bowel disease}},
    year = {2016},
    journal = {Science},
    author = {Pelczar, Penelope and Witkowski, Mario and Perez, Laura Garcia and Kempski, Jan and Hammel, Anna G and Brockmann, Leonie and Kleinschmidt, Dörte and Wende, Sandra and Haueis, Cathleen and Bedke, Tanja and Witkowski, Marco and Krasemann, Susanne and Steurer, Stefan and Booth, Carmen J and Busch, Philipp and König, Alexandra and Rauch, Ursula and Benten, Daniel and Izbicki, Jakob R and Rösch, Thomas and Lohse, Ansgar W. and Strowig, Till and Gagliani, Nicola and Flavell, Richard A. and Huber, Samuel},
    number = {6310},
    month = {10},
    pages = {358 LP--362},
    volume = {354},
    url = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/354/6310/358.abstract},
    doi = {10.1126/science.aah5903},
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage{thesis} % I don't have this style file
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{xurl} % optional -- allow line breaks at arbritary points in long URL strings

\begin{document}
\cite{Pelczar2016} % not 'Pelzcar2016'
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So these 2 errors were actually made by mistake when copying the code in here..the bibliography still won't compile. Since these commands work indepently of the thesis template I used, is there any way to change the template settings?

Comment: @stefan.0s - I'm afraid I don't have a working overleaf account and thus don't have access to the file `thesis.sty`. (Who uses such a generic, non-descript filename anyway?! There must be dozens, if not hundreds, of LaTeX style files called `thesis` out there in various corners of the Internet.) Incidentally, what exactly does "still won't compile" entail? Do you get any error and/or warning messages? If so, what to they say?

Comment: Package biblatex error: 'Incompatible packe apacite. Package todonotes warning:' the length marginparwidth is less than 2 cm and will most likely cause issues with the appearance of inserted tonotes.'  'Citation undefined on input  line ...', Package biblatex error: '\bibliographystyle invalid.'  and Latex error: 'can be used only in preamble'. (\bibliography)

Comment: @stefan.0s - The `biblatex` and `apacite6` packages are most definitely utterly incompatible with each other. Please re-read my answer: It gave two very distinct solutions: one suitable for `apacite6`, the other for `biblatex`. Trying to mix the two approaches is going to cause a crash, with absolute certainty. Choose one or the other approach, *but not both*.

Comment: So I really don't know what I'm missing but I get this 'Biblatex error: Incompatible package apacite' even though I use the commands you mentioned, i.e. \usepackage{apacite} + \bibliographystyle{apacite} , so without mixing the two approaches..? The second approach using \usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex} and 
\addbibresource{library.bib} indeed works, but then I get a different citation style with numbers in the text, as well as in the bibliography..

Comment: @stefan.0s - Sadly (but possibly not surprisingly), my divination skills are just worthless. Your description of your document setup doesn't provide nearly enough information to attempt a diagnosis of, let alone come up with cure for what is afflicting your document. Please post a *new query* with an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that gives rise to the problem behavior you wish to fix. By your own admission, the code you posted in the query above contains typos that make it non-representative of the true problems.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the suggestions